# how to check property value in two array of object values javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I have two array of object values,

`a1` and `a2`

if `idvalue` and `cidvalue` are equal,
`mainid` and `main` are true

then return

true

else return

false

```
var result = a1.find(e=> a2.find(i=>i.cidvalue===e.idvalue));

var a1=[
  {id:1, idvalue: “teamA“,mainid: true, name: “ben4”}
]

var a2 =[
  {id:2, cidvalue: “teamA”, main: true, name: ”ben3”},
  {id:3, cidvalue: undefined, main: false, name: ”ben2”},
]
```

Expected Output

```
true
```

Comment: "*if idvalue and cidvalue not matches, then return true*". Which index in the array are you talking about?

Comment: what if a1 has multiple objects?

Comment: @WaisKamal thanks for reply, updated question,  idvalue and cidvalue value matches in a1 and a2, then return true

Comment: a1 and a2 are arrays, not objects. Which indices in a1 and a2 would you like to compare?

Comment: @Nithesh thanks for reply, if multiple objects also, should check additionally check mainid and main true, will update question

Comment: @WaisKamal yes need to compare

Comment: You're code is working exactely as intended.  Add `!!` for the .find-call and you'll get your boolean value true or false instead the match that gets returned by Array.prototype.find.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `Array.every` to compare each elements in array `a1` against `a2`

```js
var a1 = [
    { id: 1, idvalue: "teamA", mainid: true, name: "ben4" },
]

var a2 = [
    { id: 2, cidvalue: "teamA", main: true, name: "ben3" },
    { id: 3, cuid: undefined, main: false, name: "ben2" },
]

var result = a1.every(e => a2.find(i => i.cidvalue === e.idvalue && e.mainid && i.main));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @Nithesh thanks for reply, I havent done that, ur code seems to be correct, thank you for timely help

Answer (score 0):

You're code is working exactely as intended.

Edit the match clause to this particular statement:

```
i => i.cidvalue === e.idvalue && e.mainid === i.main
```

And check out this working snippet with some tweaks using [Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) below to get back a boolean value indicating if the match was found or not:

```js
const a1 = [
  { id: 1, idvalue: "teamA", mainid: true, name: "ben4" },
]

const a2 = [
  { id: 2, cidvalue: "teamA", main: true, name: "ben3" },
  { id: 3, cuid: undefined, main: false, name: "ben2" },
] 

const result = a1.every(e => a2.find(i => i.cidvalue === e.idvalue && e.mainid === i.main));
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

here, I have list a2 with a1 and set if the data is more than 0 then true.

```js
var a1 = [
    { id: 1, idvalue: "teamA", mainid: true, name: "ben4" }
]

var a2 = [
    { id: 2, cidvalue: "teamA", main: true, name: "ben3" },
    { id: 3, cuid: undefined, main: false, name: "ben2" },
]

console.log(a2.filter(item => a1.find(itemm => itemm.idvalue === item.cidvalue)).length > 0);
```